# Update TOML file with variables

Tags: python, toml

I am using this code to update an existing TOML file which contains variables.
Python TOML module is not able to parse this TOML file.

How can I use this code to update the TOML file?

I have tried the 'from yaml.loader import SafeLoader' also, but that didn't help.

Code:

```py
import toml,requests,uuid,argparse
import collections.abc

class TOMLConfig:
    def __init__(self,config, file):
        self.config = config
        self.file=file

    def update(self):
        with open(self.file, "r") as f:
            existing_config = toml.load(f)

        self._update_config(existing_config, self.config)

        with open(self.file, "w") as f:
            f.write(toml.dumps(existing_config))

    def _update_config(self, existing_config, new_config):
        for key, value in new_config.items():
            if isinstance(value, collections.abc.Mapping):
                self._update_config(existing_config.setdefault(key, {}), value)
            else:
                existing_config[key] = value
```

TOML FIle

```ini
[system]
data_directory = "${DATA_DIRECTORY}"

[server]
telemetry_enabled = ${CONFIGS_TELEMETRY_ENABLED}
```

Error:

```
╰─> python3 /tmp/config.py -p  "{'data':{'shared_buffer_capacity_mb':8096,'block_cache_capacity_mb':8096,'AA_cache_capacity_mb':2048,'AA_memory_limit_mb':10240},'streaming':{'minimal_scheduling':True}}" -f /tmp/b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/toml/decoder.py", line 511, in loads
    ret = decoder.load_line(line, currentlevel, multikey,
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/toml/decoder.py", line 778, in load_line
    value, vtype = self.load_value(pair[1], strictly_valid)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/toml/decoder.py", line 910, in load_value
    raise ValueError("This float doesn't have a leading "
ValueError: This float doesn't have a leading digit
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/config.py", line 45, in <module>
    f=cobj.update()
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/tmp/config.py", line 20, in update
    existing_config = toml.load(f)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/toml/decoder.py", line 156, in load
    return loads(f.read(), _dict, decoder)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/toml/decoder.py", line 514, in loads
    raise TomlDecodeError(str(err), original, pos)
toml.decoder.TomlDecodeError: This float doesn't have a leading digit (line 5 column 1 char 88)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are just missing the quotes around the value in line 5

```
[system]
data_directory = "${DATA_DIRECTORY}"

[server]
telemetry_enabled = "${CONFIGS_TELEMETRY_ENABLED}"
```

That works fine.

Following the comment, here is how I'd edit the code:

```py
import toml,requests,uuid,argparse
import collections.abc

class TOMLConfig:
    def __init__(self,config, file):
        self.config = config
        self.file=file

    def update(self):
        with open(self.file, "r") as f:
            existing_config = toml.load(f)

        for key, value in existing_config.items():
            if value in ['true', 'false']:
                existing_config[key] = True if value == 'true' else False

        self._update_config(existing_config, self.config)

        with open(self.file, "w") as f:
            f.write(toml.dumps(existing_config))

    def _update_config(self, existing_config, new_config):
        for key, value in new_config.items():
            if isinstance(value, collections.abc.Mapping):
                self._update_config(existing_config.setdefault(key,{}), value)
            else:
                existing_config[key] = value
```

Comment: I can not have double quote.

Comment: @user87005 can you explain why? the double quotes are making the values understood as a string, once parsed there are no quotes in the variable itself, it's just the string inside the quotes.

Comment: I guess looking at the value, you're expecting a boolean. Then you are out of luck because ENV variables are strings, not boolean, and if you want them to be replaced in the TOML, they must be strings. So, you might want to parse as a string and then add some logic in your code to transform the 'true' or 'false' string(s) into a boolean before dumping it back as TOML.